# Check if session exists php and print an 'echo'

Tags: php, session

I'm crating a little web form, it will display inputs depending of the country, state and so on.

In the form I passed the POST info to SESSION's, in other file I will catch the information but I would like check if the POST info was entered write it in a text file.

Part of the form file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['ZIP'] = $_POST['ZIP'];
$_SESSION['usuariorio'] = $_POST['usuariost'];
//......
?>
```

File to catch the info and print it into a text file:

```
<?php
sesson_start()
if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
$Z118_MESSAGE .= "<font style='color:#9c0000;'>|</font> [Client Number]  = <font style='color:#0070ba;'>".$_SESSION['cliente']."</font><br>\n";}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['NIP'])){
$Z118_MESSAGE .= "<font style='color:#9c0000;'>|</font> [NIP]            = <font style='color:#0070ba;'>".$_SESSION['NIP']."</font><br>\n";}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['usuariorio'])){
$Z118_MESSAGE .= "<font style='color:#9c0000;'>|</font> [ST Rio User]    = <font style='color:#0070ba;'>".$_SESSION['usuariorio']."</font><br>\n";}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['ZIP'])){
$Z118_MESSAGE .= "<font style='color:#9c0000;'>|</font> [ZIP]            = <font style='color:#0070ba;'>".$_SESSION['ZIP']."</font><br>\n";}
if(isset($_SESSION['membersince'])){
$Z118_MESSAGE .= "<font style='color:#9c0000;'>|</font> [MEMBER ID]   = <font style='color:#0070ba;'>".$_SESSION['m_id']."</font><br>\n";}
}
        $save = fopen("../../../1918.html","a");
        fwrite($save,$Z118_MESSAGE);
        fclose($sace);
?>
```

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: I don't know what the question is, but you need to call `sesson_start()` before your access `$_SESSION`. You do that in the first code block, but not the second one.

Comment: The script doesnt write the SESSION info in the text file. I forget write sesson_start() in the code block, but it is in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second php file you want to access $_SESSION. You need to add

```
session_start();
```

at the begin of your file.